# How to create polygon procedural shape?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, procedural, shader-nodes

I want to create alternative to Agama Materials polygon procedural shape in Blender.
[image]

It should have any number of side and explode, and it should be able to explode.
I tried a lot of technics, radial shape works, but I can't straighten sides of a figure, unfortunately.
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: @MartyFouts I belive you didn't understand, I want it as a procedural texture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maths in this answer is a combination of [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/168499/35559), and [this remark](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/237779/35559). Those examples demonstrate: a) how to make a polygon-shader, and b) how to make a stripe of constant thickness about a vector.

Here, the angle `theta` for any given shading point is given by a radial gradient, *Ping-Ponged* to divide it into spokes.

In this case, a spoke-stripe is made using `sin(theta)*radius > a constant`: half the stripe's thickness. The remaining bit of trig. in the tree increases the size of the polygon by just the right amount, so, when it's masked by stripes of a given thickness, the segments remain the same size, and it appears to explode. That section is coloured green.

[image]

The input parameters are:

- `Sides`, the number of sides of the polygon
- `Size`, the distance from the centre to a flat side of the polygon
- `Explode`, the half-thickness of the stripe mask across the polygon: half  the radial gap between the segments.

[image]

You could add some nodes to tweak the inputs before grouping the tree, to suit your purposes. Rotation could be done in the *Mapping* node. I'm not sure what your reference's 'Gradient' means.. if you need that, call back.

[image]

Comment: You are amazing, Thank you a lot